# C# Unit Testing: How do I set a Lazy<T>.ValueCreated to false?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, singleton, lazy-evaluation

Basically, I have a unit test that gets a singleton instance of a class. Some of my tests required me to mock this singleton, so when I do Foo.Instance I get a different type of instance.

The problem is that my checks are passing individually, but failing overall because one test is interfering with another.

I tried to do a TestCleanup where I set: `Foo_Accessor._instance = null;` but that didn't work. What I really need is `Foo_Accessor._instance.IsValueCreated = false;` (_instance is a Lazy).

Any way to unset the Lazy object that I didn't think of?

Comment: Can you post some code so that we can see why Foo_Accessor._instance = null isn't working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not do: `Foo_Accessor._instance = new Lazy<Foo>(Something);`

Make sure the "Something" is exactly the same as what your Foo class is doing.

Comment: Yeah, put something like this in the per-test setup phase.

Comment: Well, either in the setup or cleanup. Either way you're basically setting up your Lazy instance back to a lazy state.